# Trouble replacing text with JavaScript. Please help

Tags: javascript

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

$('h').innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, "<span style='color: red;'>hello</span>");
```

It doesn't work. What happened?

Comment: ummm you have an html element with id=h?

Answer (score 4):

`replace` returns a string and does not automatically assign it to the element.

```
$('h').innerHTML = $('h').innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, "<span style='color: red;'>hello</span>");
```

Answer (score 3):

replace() does not happen in-place; you need to assign the result to the destination you want:

```
var newText = $('h').innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, "<span style='color: red;'>hello</span>");
// Do something with newText
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need your first function, JQuery takes care of that automatically via a selector. Also, setting innerHTML should replace all the existing content of it anyway, so you don't need to explicitly state replace after that.

```
$('#h').html(/hello/g, "<span style='color: red;'>hello</span>");
```

Also, I think your quotes were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the value back to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

$('h').innerHTML = $('h').innerHTML.replace("hello", "<span style='color: red;'>hello</span>");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/LBAn6/